# Pass a variable to an event listener

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to be able to pass a variable to an event. After searching, I've found out that it is impossible and a lot of people just used an anonymous function instead. The problem is, the variable that I need to pass is unique so I can't use anonymous function. Any idea how do I solve this? Here's how my code goes by the way:

- Function that creates "note"
- This note is either good or bad, (unique)
- Add a move event
- Remove the note if it goes beyond the stage
- Minus or add points depending on the type of note. (not yet coded)

```
function SpawnNote(rpos:int):void
{   
    var spawn:int;  
    spawn = int(Math.random() * notes.length);          

rtemp = rpos;

if(rsn%2==1)
{
    if(rtemp==1)
    {
        rpos = int(Math.random() * 2)+2;            
    }

    if(rtemp==2)
    {
        rpos = int(Math.random() * 2);
        if(rpos==0)
        {
            rpos = 3;
        }
    }

    if(rtemp==3)
    {
        rpos = int(Math.random() * 2)+1;                
    }

}


var note:MovieClip = new notes[spawn]();

addChild(note);

if (rpos ==1)
{
    note.x = pos1;

}
else if (rpos==2)
{
    note.x = pos2;

}
else if (rpos==3)
{
    note.x = pos3;

}


note.y = 150;
note.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveNote); 
note.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CheckNote(spawn));      

}

function MoveNote(event:Event):void
{
    var note:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;
    note.y +=  15;
    if (note.y >= stage.stageHeight + 50)
    {

        note.visible = true;
        note.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveNote);
        note.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CheckNote);
        this.removeChild(note);     
    }   
}
```

Comment: It is impossible only if you are extremely lazy and don't want to write a custom event class with which you can set as many variables as you want. Having a problem passing variable with an event is only a matter of being lazy or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a field to the note that would signify if it's good or bad, and query `note` as its class or `MovieClip`, not just `DisplayObject`.

```
note.bad = ... // some expression dependent on "spawn"
function CheckNote(e:Event):void {
    var note:MovieClip=e.target as MovieClip;
    if (note==null) return;
    if (note.bad) ... // process, now you can query if the note is bad.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vesper the flash God.